# Creating a form with drop downs using MySQL data

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently having a problem outputting my form which uses mysql data. It may be because of my placing of code as this is all new to me. The current output (Updated) looks like this: http://gyazo.com/18ee007c6e3618245706398d5a1e0ed3

The output should display like: Event (e.g. Long Jump A) next to drop down. Also its currently only showing 1 (or 2) loops - there is around 25 events it should be showing. If anyone can see why its not displaying all the events then please advise on correcting this. (Code been updated)

```
echo "<form method =\"POST\">";
  if ($result = $con->query("SELECT Event.Name FROM event")) 
  {                                     
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {               
           echo $row['Name'] . ' '; // . ' <br> ';          
           if ($result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Student.Forename, Student.Surname, Student_ID " .
                                "FROM Student, Teacher " .
                                    "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Form = 'C'")) 
           {                        
              if ($result->num_rows) 
              {             
                  echo "<select name ='Student_ID'>";                       
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                  {                                     
                     echo "<option value ='" . $row['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row['Forename'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . "</option>";
                  }
                  echo "</select>";                 
              }                                                                 
           }                
        }
   }        
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 "</form>"?

Comment: @Masiorama  forgot to delete one, when uploaded, removed 1 now

Comment: [what have you tried so far??](http://www.phpsuperblog.com/php/html-form-drop-down-menu-with-data-from-mysql-datebase-as-options/)

Comment: Then you should update the question to what actual code we are dealing with.

Comment: @CodingHorror the code above however getting an unexpected output, the expected result should look like this: events: http://gyazo.com/e5a76a70fad48271ee096d2761e3356d with the a drop down next to each event: http://gyazo.com/0532c5f790357d68de7502f0004093a3

Comment: @Masiorama its updated now, can you spot the problem?

Comment: you are messing with the variables' name: you are using them for different objects, reassigning twice. You did that at least with $result and $row. Use better naming, without colliding.

Comment: Nope sorry. You should not use this as a forum anyway. If you are studying and still getting accustomed with programming there are plenty of places better suited for that. :)

Comment: @Masiorama ok thanks anyway - any solutions to current output??  the variables was the main problem, output now looks like: gyazo.com/f4fe6ae159b573adcb9f15702288104f any solution to first and last line being next to a drop down AND swapping the placing of the events and the dropdowns?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename second $row

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

to

```
while ($row_1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

and use $row_1

Comment: just tried the different variable names didn't make a different change to the output

Comment: Still what he pointed out is definitely an issue, so you need to fix it.

Comment: @Masiorama the output looks like this now: http://gyazo.com/18ee007c6e3618245706398d5a1e0ed3 its only looping through the events once I think

Comment: Try also the second $result to change $result_1

Comment: @crazy_ljuba the variables was the main problem, output now looks like: http://gyazo.com/f4fe6ae159b573adcb9f15702288104f any solution to first and last line being next to a drop down AND swapping the placing of the events and the dropdowns?? thanks

Comment: You can style it with css, e.g. you can add to your echo "<select name ='Student_ID'> class='someclass' ";  and for the name you can do like  echo "<p class='paragraphclass' > ". $row['Name'] . ' </p> ';  And both classes should have float:left; While the parent div should have some width... ( optimal solution  )

Comment: And would be nice to accept this as an answer :-) so i can comment to other posts etc..

Answer (score -1):

`<select>` tag put outside of while loop.

```
echo "<select>";
while (){
//do stuff
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: the select tags are outside the while loop

Comment: That's not the problem.

Comment: @Masiorama Its something to do with the loops, but not entirely sure